# Retrieve and display two sets of data from option form

Tags: php, forms

I'm working on a website with a functionality where the user select two dropdown options in a form and the target page shows the name of those options as well as information specific to those selected items.

To make an example version for this post; a form for travel between two U.S cities that will reveal travel options & information for that specific journey.

I have three tables in the database that I'm using (Cities, Route (bridging table), Options). So far I've been able to create the form and use POST to send through the ID number of the cities selected to be able to pull the information needed for that route onto the results page.

The only issue I'm having is I can't seem to figure out how to pass both the ID and name of the cities to the result page. I require the ID number for the bridging table to pull the option information, and the names of the selected cities displayed on the page. I have it set up like this:

Form page

```
<form method="post" action="result.php">
  <select name="departOption">
  <?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM cities;"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $CityNumber = $row["No"];
        $CityName = $row["City"];
        ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $CityNumber ?>"><?php echo $CityName ?> </option>
          <?php
      } 
  } else { 
      echo "-"; 
  } ?>
  </select>
  <select name="arriveOption">
  <?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM cities;"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $CityNumber = $row["No"];
        $CityName = $row["City"];
        ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $CityNumber ?>"><?php echo $CityName ?> </option>
          <?php
      } 
  } else { 
      echo "-"; 
  } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit the form"/>
</form>
```

result.php

```
<?php
  $option1 = isset($_POST['departOption']) ? $_POST['departOption'] : false;
  if ($option1) {
      echo "<p>".($_POST['departOption']) ."</p>";
  } else {
    echo "Depart Option is required";
    exit; 
  }
  $option2 = isset($_POST['arriveOption']) ? $_POST['arriveOption'] : false;
  if ($option2) {
      echo "<p>".($_POST['arriveOption']) ."</p>";
  } else {
    echo "Arrive Option is required";
    exit; 
  }
$query = "SELECT * FROM `route`,options  WHERE route.Depart_City = " . $option1 . " AND route.Arrive_City = " . $option2 . " AND route.Information = options.No";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      $Option_Description = $row["Desc"];
      ?>
        <p> <?php echo $Option_Description ?></p>
      <?php
    } 
} else { 
    echo "No options available."; 
} ?>
```

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: FYI: You don't need to pass the name to `result.php`. You are already passing the ID of the city, meaning you can just use a query to retrieve the selected city's name

Comment: Yep, as above- you don't need to pass through the names. Just get them out of the database again as part of your query simply add a couple of JOINs to the Cities table)

Comment: querying the db twice with exactly the same query to build two identical (except in name) `select` elements seems peculiar! The results from one query can be used to build both sets of `option` values.

Comment: @DarkBee you're right i can just query the database for the name, thanks. im just making the basic code to get the function to work and will make it secure after thanks for the tip though

Comment: @ADyson thank you for the advice i will try that

Comment: @Professor Abronsius you're right, i copied and pasted it without thinking but i only need to query it once. i will fix that. thanks

Comment: `im just making the basic code to get the function to work and will make it secure after`...why? What's the point of doing it twice? It's actually not any more difficult to it properly the first time, and then you don't need to write and test the SQL part more than once! If you already know it's not secure to do it like this, then there's no reason at all to do it like this :-).